# Google vision Bar code Scanner not working for android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, google-vision

In our app we are using the Google vision Bar code Scanner to scan QR-codes. This was working fine until we tested Android version 6.0 (Marshmallow). I tried to find some documentation with supported version but could not find anything. The scanner doesn't crash but it can't recognize or find QR-codes. Does Google vision Bar code Scanner support Android 6.0?

Comment: Provide the crash logs and version of dependencies that you are currently using in your project.

Comment: I am using BarcodeScanner.XF v5.0.2 with Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2012.

Comment: I asked this same question to the author of the library and he says that version 6.0  has not been tested I so reckon it's not supported yet.

Comment: What Camera API you're using? 
Recommendation: use CameraX API. It works best with Google MLK.